# How to jQuery an XML file over a PHP-script and parse it right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, parsing

I already tried several methods getting my xml-script parsed in java, but i can't figure it out!

I have 2 files. 
mysql_get.php is returning an XML script if it is called.
post_alert.html is fetching the XML script from mysql_get.php over jQuery $.post(..) as shown below:

```
function init2() {

    var response;
    $.post("mysql_get.php", function (data) {
        response = data;
        alert(response)
    });
    var xml;
    xml = $.parseXML(response);
    alert($(response).find("item").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("id")
    }));
}
```

After hit a button which call init2(), i get the response message in xml style as i can see by the alert popup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="uft-8"?>
<root>
<collection collection="locationPoint">
    <item id="1">
        <latitude>23.4442</latitude>
        <longitude>51.2341</longitude>
    </item>

    <item id="2">
        <latitude>2849.24</latitude>
        <longitude>213.132</longitude>
    </item>
</collection>
```

But the alert doesn't popup "1" in addition as I wished for correct parsing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of things:
 Line 1 of you xml file should read UTF-8 not UFT-8
 Line 2 should be deleted, else make sure you have a closing  tag, invalid xml

Then here is a little example that I hope helps:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dc"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'mysql_get.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: function(data) {
                    $(data).find('item').each(function () {
                        $('#dc').append($(this).attr('id') + '<br/>')
                    });
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    $('#dc').html('error');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The A in **AJAX** stands for asynchronous. The code after `$.post(..)` is executed right after [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is called, regardless of the response state.

You have to move the `var xml..`-code **inside** the `$.post` call.
Also, [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) only loops through the elements, without returning the IDs. Use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to create an object consisting of the ids, and [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) to get an array representation of it.

```
function init2() {
    $.post("mysql_get.php", function(data) {
        var response = data;
        var xml = $($.parseXML(response));
        alert(response.find("item").map(function () {
            return $(this).attr("id")
        }).toArray() );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [XML manipulation with jQuery](http://www.fatihacet.com/lab/xml/)